# Operator overloading in C++ to manage playlists of music

Tags: c++, c++11, vectors, overloading

I've built this little C++ program just to take some rust off my coding skills
since it's been ages since the last time I coded something.

The purpose is to organize my music, so I've built the classes
'song' and 'playlist' with some methods which could come in handy - maybe -
such as printing on file the list of songs in the playlist and so on.
I'm not sure that `std::vector` is the right choice to store the songs in the 
playlist (as private member). Would a `std::set` be more efficient?

Given a list of songs I wanted to sort out if each and every
one of the songs in the list appeared at least in one playlist,
with each playlist representing a musical genre.

I was also interested in listing the "overlaps" between two different
playlists, to get a sort of Venn Diagram of my music. I've accomplished 
that by overloading the operators + and - for the playlist, and by
defining a function "intersection".

I'm defenetly not sure about the best way to handle the `const` functions.

I've used the following libraries:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Here it is the implementation of the class song:

```
class song {
private:
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    std::string album;
public:
    song(std::string tit) : title(tit), author("? "), album("? ") { }
    song(std::string tit, std::string au, std::string al) : title(tit), author(au), album(al) { }

    const std::string gettitle() {return title;}
    const std::string getauthor() {return author;}
    const std::string getalbum() {return album;}

    const bool operator==(song & a) {
        if(title == a.gettitle()) {
            if(author == a.getauthor()) {
                if(album == a.getalbum()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }else{ return false; }

    }

    void playsong() { 
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\"" << title << "\"" << ", by " << author << ", \n";
        std::cout << "from the album \"" << album << "\"." << std::endl;
    }
    void showtitle() { std::cout << title << std::endl; }
    void showauthor() { std::cout << author << std::endl; }
    void showalbum() { std::cout << album << std::endl; }
    void showall() { 
        std::cout << title << " | " << author;
        std::cout << " | " << album << std::endl;
    }

};
```

And of the class playlist:

```
class playlist {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<song> list;
public:
    playlist() : name(" ") {}
    playlist(std::string nam) : name(nam) {}
    playlist(playlist & x, std::string nam) {
        name = nam;
        list = x.getlist();
    }

    playlist operator=(const playlist & x) {
        list = x.getlist();
        name = x.getname();
        return *this;
    }

    const playlist operator+( const playlist & x) {
        playlist z(*this);
        for(int i=0; i<(x.getlist()).size(); i++) { 
            if (false == this->findsong((x.getlist())[i])){ 
                z.addsong((x.getlist())[i]);
            }
        }
        z.setname(this->getname() + "+" + x.getname());
        return z;
    }

    const playlist operator-(const playlist & x) {
        playlist z(*this);
        for(int i=0; i<(x.getlist()).size(); i++) {
            if (this->findsong((x.getlist())[i])){ 
                z.deletesong((x.getlist())[i]);
            }
        }
        z.setname(this->getname() + "-" + x.getname());
        return z;
    }

    std::vector<song> getlist() const { return list; }
    std::string getname() const { return name; }
    song getsong(std::vector<song>::iterator it) const { return *it; } 

    std::vector<song>::iterator getsong(song & x) {
        std::vector<song>::iterator it;
        it = list.begin();
        while (it != list.end()) {
            if(*(it) == x) break;
            it ++;
        }

        return it;
    }
    void setname(std::string nam) { name = nam; }
    void addlist(std::string file) {
        std::ifstream in(file);
        std::string line;
        while(std::getline(in, line)) {

            std::stringstream linestream(line);
            std::string tit, au, al;
            getline(linestream, tit, '\t');
            getline(linestream, au, '\t');
            getline(linestream, al);

            song x(tit, au, al);        
            this->addsong(x);   
        }
        in.close();
    }

    void addsong(song x) { list.push_back(x); }

    void deletesong(song x) {
        int cont=0;
        std::vector<song>::iterator it;
        it = list.begin();
        for(auto el : list) {
            if(el == x){
                list.erase(it);
                std::vector<song>::iterator it;
                it = list.begin() + cont;
            }
            cont ++;
        }
    }

    bool findsong(song x) {
        bool tobe = false;
        for (auto el : list) {
            if(el == x) tobe = true;
        }
        return tobe;
    }

    void showplaylist() {
        int cont=0;
        std::vector<song>::iterator it;
        it = list.begin();
        std::cout << std::endl << name << std::endl << std::endl;
        while (it != list.end()) {
            cont++;
            std::cout << cont << ") ";
            it->showall();
            it++;
        }
    }

    void playplaylist() {
        int cont=0;
        std::vector<song>::iterator it;
        it = list.begin();
        std::cout << std::endl << name << std::endl << std::endl;
        while (it != list.end()) {
            cont++;
            std::cout << cont << ") ";
            it->playsong();
            it++;
        }
    }

    std::ofstream printplaylist(std::string nam) {
        std::ofstream out(nam + ".dat");
        std::vector<song>::iterator it;
        it = list.begin();
        out << std::endl << name << std::endl << std::endl;
        while (it != list.end()) {
            out << it->gettitle() << "\t";
            out << it->getauthor() << "\t";
            out << it->getalbum() << std::endl;

            it++;
        }
        out.close();
        return out;
    }
};
```

This is the only function I wrote:

```
playlist intersection(playlist & x, playlist & y) {
    playlist z, q, t;
    z = x + y;
    t = x - y;
    q = y - x; 
    z = z - q;
    z = z - t;
    z.setname("(" + x.getname() + ")^(" + y.getname() + ")" );
    return z;
}
```

In the `main` I tried my methods to check if they worked fine. The playlist are "loaded" in my program through some files.dat wich have the following structure:

> Title \tab Author \tab Album

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Constructors

The better way to write the constructor is

```cpp
song(std::string tit, std::string au = "? ", std::string al = "? ")
    : title(tit), author(au), album(al) { }
```

That way specifying the title and the author but leaving the album default is possible. Also you only need a single constructor now. You can further improve by using `title(std::move(tit))` to skip a memory allocation.

## Privacy

Through keeping `title`, `author` and `album` `private` and only providing functions like `gettitle` and `showtitle` you sort of made those read-only. Why? What is the danger having a `song` and setting the title of it? If someone wants to do it they can do

```cpp
s = song{"new title", s.getauthor(), s.getalbum()};
```

which is just awkward. You didn't actually gain privacy while inconveniencing your users. I'd make all the members `public` and remove the getters until there is internal logic that keeps the members synchronized and you cannot guarantee it when users can change the members.

## Warnings

Enable them. They are really useful. There is a bug in `const bool operator==(song & a)` but it's not really worth learning about because [a compiler can spot it](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5218fe771890c162) so you don't have to.

## Const correctness

When comparing 2 `song`s those should not change and only being able to compare modifiable `song`s is weird. The correct signature for that is `bool operator==(const song & a) const`. The `const` on the right refers to `*this`, meaning when you do `s1 == s2` then `s1` is allowed to be `const`. The `const` in the middle refers to the right side, `s2` in the example which we also want to allow to be `const`. The `const` in the front you had refers to the `bool` and besides very weird edge cases you don't want to return `const` objects by value. The same applies to `gettitle` and arguably those functions should return a `const std::string &` to avoid making a copy.

## Comparisons

If you want lexicographic compares you can use

```cpp
return std::tie(title, author, album) == std::tie(a.gettitle(), a.getauthor(), a.getalbum());
```

It doesn't look that much better than what you wrote, but it fixed the bug I hinted at when talking about warnings and when doing `operator <` this becomes much easier than doing it by hand. C++20 is not that far away and then defaulting `operator <=>` should make this convenient.

## Separation of Concerns

`song` prints to `std::cout`. It really shouldn't. As a user of your class I should be the one who decides how and where things are printed to. I want to print to `std::clog` for example. For that you can add a function `std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const song &s)` which prints its elements to `os`. Through inheritance I can now do `std::cout << song{};` or `std::fstream("/tmp/songs.txt") << song{};` or whatever I want. Although if you make the members `public` this is probably no longer necessary. Also users can add their own way of printing.

## Extra Parenthesis

`x.getlist()` has lots of extra parenthesis around making the code less readable. I find `findsong((x.getlist())[i])` particularly jarring. `findsong(x.getlist()[i])` is better.

## [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

`if (false == this->findsong((x.getlist())[i]))` should better be written as `if (not findsong(x.getlist()[i]))`. Using `not` over `!` is a style choice some people find weird and you don't need to follow it, but yoda conditions are harmful to readability and with warnings enabled have no upside.

Comment: I don't have time for `playlist` right now, but maybe it's a start.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'll start by improving the song class. If you have time later to check also the playlist class it would be awesome

Comment: @Gitana The other answer pretty much covered that already, but I added 2 points I didn't see there. `for (auto &element : container)` is a generally useful idiom to use for iterating over elements of a container.

Answer (score 2):

Single-responsibility: the `show*()` methods in `song` don't provide any benefit, since we already have suitable `get*()` methods which can be used more flexibly.  Thus, `song` needn't require `<iostream>` or the like.

Returning `const std::string` here probably isn't what you meant:

> ```
> const std::string gettitle() {return title;}
> const std::string getauthor() {return author;}
> const std::string getalbum() {return album;}
> ```

More useful would be

```
std::string gettitle() const {return title;}
std::string getauthor() const {return author;}
std::string getalbum() const {return album;}
```

This misplaced `const` also affects operator `==`, which also has scope to be simpler and clearer.  Any time we have an `if`/`else` where the branches return `true` or `false` consider just using a boolean expression directly for `return`:

```
bool operator==(const song& a) const
{
    return title == a.title
        && author == a.author
        && album == a.album;
}
```

We can also access the private members of `a`, since it's of our class.

Consider providing operator `!=`, too:

```
bool operator!=(const song& a) const
{ return !(*this == a); }
```

The constructors of `song` accept `std::string` by value; we should use `std::move` to avoid copying again (and we can use default arguments to reduce duplication):

```
explicit song(std::string title, std::string author = "? ", std::string album = "? ")
    : title(std::move(title)),
      author(std::move(author)),
      album(std::move(album))
{ }
```

(Note `explicit`, because we don't want this class to be considered for implicit conversion from string).

---

One of the `playlist` constructors doesn't initialise members, but uses assignment in the body instead.  Prefer initialisers, and consolidate using default arguments:

```
explicit playlist(std::string name = "")
    : name(std::move(name)),
      list()
{}
playlist(const playlist & x, std::string name)
    : name(std::move(name)),
      list(x.list)
{}
```

Operator `=` should return a *reference* rather than a copy (`g++ -Weffc++` catches this):

```
playlist& operator=(const playlist & x) {
//     ^^^
```

But there's absolutely no need to declare this operator - follow the Rule of Zero, and let the compiler generate it and the copy/move constructors too.

Operator `+` performs set addition, which surprised me - normally, I would expect concatenation, like my existing Empeg Car player.  Even if that's what's required, we can improve it.  Any time we use a loop like `for (std::size_t i=0;  i < container.size();  ++i)` and then only use `i` for indexing, we can replace with a range-based `for` loop:

```
playlist operator+(const playlist& x) const
{
    playlist z(*this, name + "+" + x.name);
    for (auto& song: x.list) {
        if (!findsong(song)) {
            z.addsong(song);
        }
    }
    return z;
}
```

This still scales poorly, as the linear search in `findsong` is performed for each song to be added.  If we make `song` sortable or hashable, we could use a `std::set` to identify duplicates, at a cost of some overhead initialising the set.

I don't see why we have this method in the public interface:

> ```
> song getsong(std::vector<song>::iterator it) const { return *it; }
> ```

That's something any calling code can do much more simply, and I'd argue that we probably shouldn't be giving out such iterators anyway.

The other `getsong` seems to exactly implement `std::find()`, and I don't see the value to users.

In `removesong`, we don't need to keep count with `cont`.  The right way to cope with iterator invalidation is to use the return value from `erase()`:

```
void deletesong(const song& x)
{
    auto it = list.begin();
    while (it != list.end()) {
        if (*it == x){
            it = list.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

However, with that said, the real way to implement "remove all matching" is to use the [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
#include <algorithm>

void deletesong(const song& x)
{
    list.erase(std::remove(list.begin(), list.end(), x), list.end());
}
```

In a similar vein, `findsong()` can be simplified using `std::find()`:

```
bool findsong(const song& x) const
{
    return std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), x) != list.end();
}
```